# Can I use std::bind to "attach" a state to a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I need to pass a std::function to some algorithm. The type of the function is

```
typedef std::function<bool(const double&)> Condition;
```

In the simplest case this function will look like this

```
bool simpleCondition(const double& d){return d<0.001;}
```

Now I want to pass the same condition but only if the condition is fullfilled a number of times in a row, the function should return true. I tried the following

```
class RepeatingCondition{
    public:
        static Condition getRepeatingCondition(Condition c,int reps){
            return std::bind(&RepeatingCondition::evalCondition,
                                   RepeatingCondition(c,reps),_1);
        }
    private:
        RepeatingCondition(Condition cc,int reps) : counter(0), 
                                              reps(reps),cond(cc){}
        bool evalCondition(const double& d){
            if (cond(d)){counter += 1;}
            else {counter = 0;}
            return (counter >= reps);
        }
        Condition cond;
        int counter,reps;
};
```

My compiler does not complain and it seems to work as expected. However, I dont really understand why (with a simple function pointer it would not work, right?). Also, I would like to know if there is a simpler way to achieve the same.

Comment: With a lambda: `static Condition getRepeatingCondition(Condition c,int reps){ int counter = 0; return [=](double const d) mutable { return if(c(d)) counter += 1; else counter = 0; return counter >= reps; } }`

Comment: Note that you can simplify the above code by renaming `RepeatingCondition::evalCondition` to `operator()`, make it public, and the use `std::bind(RepeatigCondition(c, reps), _1)` in `getRepeatingCondition`.

Comment: Is a static method with a static counter out of the question? That could simplify things a bit more, allowing you to ditch the object completely. Note: I do not claim this is the best solution for I do not know your other use cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can I use `std::bind` to “attach” a state to a function?

Yes, that's exactly what it's for. It returns an object (of an unspecified class type) containing the function pointer and all the bound arguments, with a function call `operator()` to invoke the function with those arguments.

`std::function` then encapsulates that object, allowing it to be passed around and invoked without knowing its type. This technique is known as *type erasure*.

> with a simple function pointer it would not work, right?

Indeed, you need something more complicated for this to work. That's what `std::bind` and `std::function` provide.

> Also, I would like to know if there is a simpler way to achieve the same.

A lambda is often more readable than a bind expression:

```
static Condition getRepeatingCondition(Condition c,int reps){
    RepeatingCondition rep(c,reps);
    return [rep](double d) mutable {return rep.evalCondition(d);};
}
```

Comment: To be fair, a simple function pointer could work if you added a static variable into it. E.g. `bool rep() {static int counter = 0; return (counter++ > 5);}` or something. Of course you would need additional logic within the function to reset the variable if you wanted to use it more than once.

Comment: @cartographer: That would only allow a single instance (with weird behaviour if you created a second).

Comment: I didn't say it was a good idea, obviously one should prefer an approach like what's in your answer, just that if for some reason you can't, there are other ways.

Comment: @MikeSeymour actually I thought that maybe it is possible to completely avoid writing a class when I was asking for a "simpler way". However, from the comments I got I understand that what I did wasnt that wrong ;). I marked your answer as accepted even though Nassers approach seems to be just as good.

Answer (score 1):

Since @Mike Seymour already took the lambda approach, I'll propose an alternative using functors, which could be a good alternative to the code in the question:

```
class RepeatingCondition {
    Condition m_condition;
    int       m_counter, m_reps;

public:
    RepeatingCondition(Condition c, int reps) 
    : m_condition(c), m_counter(0) , m_reps(reps) { }

    bool operator()(const double d) {
        if(m_codition(d)) { 
            m_counter += 1;
        } else {
            m_counter = 0;
        }

        return (m_counter >= m_reps);
    }
};
```

Now, you can create the instance you want using the `RepeatingCondition` class, like so:

```
RepeatingCondition repCond(checkDouble, 12);

if(repCond(5.4)) { // calls the operator() overload
    std::cout << "condition met\n";
}
```

Comment: is this C++11? I just started to like the cool new stuff, but now I am forced to work in an envirenment where I cannot use C++11 :(

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Lucky for you, this is not C++11, so you can use it without any problems!